# jQuery: how to apply same predefined behavior for new appended element?

Tags: jquery

I have a click method for a class of div tags

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="detail">abc</div>
<div class="click">click here</div>
<div ckass="click">click here</div>
</div>
<script>

${.click}.click(function(){
$(#wrapper).append("<div class="click">added</div>");
});
</script>
```

When I click on "click here" the script added new div. But when I tried to click on the new added div, nothing happened. Please show me how to make the new added also clickable. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `on()` method. Then it would apply for the newly added `<div>` as well:

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '.click', function (event) {
    $('#wrapper').append("<div class='click'>added</div>");
});
```

If you would like to use `bind()`, which `click(f)` is a proxy for `bind('click', f)` then do the following:

```
var handler = function (event) {
    $('<div class="click">added</div>')
        .appendTo($("#wrapper"))
        .bind('click', handler);
};
$('.click').click(handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some spelling mistakes.
Try This code :

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="detail">abc</div>
<div class="click">click here</div>
<div class="click">click here</div>
</div>
<script>

var handler = function (event) {
$('<div class="click">added</div>').appendTo($("#wrapper")).bind('click', handler);
};
$('.click').click(handler);
</script>
```

Comment: It would still not attach the handler to the new element.

Comment: I see it the handler dosen't work, you can use function instead of all of this.

Answer (score 0):

try `.on()` handler, In your case you were binding events to direct elems which were present in the dom while `<div class='click'>added</div>` inserted in dom afterwards, so click on it will not work, For this you have to delegate the event to the existing closest parent elem which is `#wrapper` or you can directly call on `document` instead `#wrapper` which is parent of all elems in the dom:

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '.click', function(){
   $('#wrapper').append("<div class='click'>added</div>");
});
```

see this in action: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/RcPnN/</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. It works for me. By the way, could you recommend me a good book on jQuery? Thanks again.

Comment: When i started using jquery somewhere before 6-10 months earlier i used to read `jQuery Novice to Ninja`. I feel this has very basic knowledge to start.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="detail">abc</div>
<div onclick='Add()'>click here</div>
<div onclick='Add()'>click here</div>
</div>
<script>
function Add(){
$("#wrapper").append("<div onclick='Add()'>added</div>");
}
</script>
```